# constructing CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

While trying to constructing a CW complex of Moebius band, I come up an construction which I am not sure about it. The construction is as follows: Attach two 1-cells to a 0-cell. Then attached a 2-cell in a way such that it starts at left half of upper circle,pass through 0-cell, arrived at right half of lower circle, then continued from left half of lower circle, to 0-cell, finally right half of upper circle. Is it a Moebius band, or something else?

**Edit**
I should add details of the attaching map. By attaching two 1-cells to 0-cell, I mean the map $f_{1},f_{2}:S^{0}\rightarrow \{0\}$, $f_{1}(\pm1)=f_{2}(\pm1)=0$. Then we formed a "8" shape figure.

For the 2-cell, we attached $S^{1}$ by starting at the northpole of upper circle, then draw a "S" shape to southpole, then going back along the remaining part. So the concept is drawing a "8" from north pole.

Comment: Maybe you could describe the attaching map in more detail?  What you wrote above, depending on orientations, sounds like a projective plane.  A compact Moebius band needs to have a boundary circle.

Comment: Isn't it the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3945639?

Comment: No, I made a mistake in that one, the one I made was not an CW complex

Comment: Then I suggest that you delete your other question.